# Run a commandline script of changed (switched) user in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to add a text to a file that can be access only from a certain account id "appid" and passwd "passx"
I tried following code, which does not work.

```
import os, subprocess
text=str('23.33%')
cmd = ['su', 'appid', '-c echo text >> /tofhisfile.txt']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate('passx')
```

also this does not work

```
os.system('su appid -c echo text >> /tothisfile.txt')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use target_user's password using `su` utility only in interactive mode (or use `expect` utility along with `su` authentication). If you want to authenticate one user as another using `sudo` utility - you should write appropriative rules in `/etc/sudoers` file as root (so your source_user would not be asked for password at all). Also note, that when you're using sudo use `sudo -u root /bin/sh -c 'echo "root cat write anywhere" > /etc/anywhere'`, in case `sudo -u root echo "root can write anywhere" > /etc/anywhere` you'll receive permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a list along with `shell=True`. You don't want to do the latter, but even if you did, shells take strings, so you'd need the same kind of string as your second example.

Anyways, you probably want to just do all this outside your script. So assume you've been `setuid`'ed properly already (though this would be what you'd use if you were doing it inside your script – `os.setuid`) and just write to the file, and then run the script with `su whoever -c python mything.py`.